# Restful API Endpoints for one to many and many to many relationships

Tags: web-services, express, restful-architecture, endpoint

This is the scenario :

In a university, there are many departments and one department has many programs  ( One to Many ) and I want to fetch **'All the Programs that belong to a particular Department'**

How to best define restful endpoints for such cases in expressJs(node)??

Also how to determine endpoints for many to many and one to one relationship?

Thank You !!

Answer (score 0):

Express will handle responses and requests for you. It doesn't care about the logic within, if you are doing a restful service, fetching data from a db or whatever operation you are doing.

Now if you are using a SQL DB I recommend you look into Sequelize to have an ORM and create simple endpoints for CRUD operations, there are a lot of examples out there and you can quickly find the answer to your question.

If you are using Mongo I recommend you use Mongoose and you will also find a lot of examples to create a simple CRUD restful service.

But remember express and node don't dictate what db engine and ORM (optional) you use, therefore they don't dictate how relationships are handled.